Getting error :[WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
While running a python script iam getting the below error
Failed to initialize WebDriver or load configuration: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gourav\Downloads\Automation_Tool\Automation_Tool\demo.py", line 207, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\gourav\Downloads\Automation_Tool\Automation_Tool\demo.py", line 195, in main
    driver.quit()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'driver' referenced before assignment

I am running a python script
def main():
    try:
        
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
        print("@@@@@@@@-driver@@@@@@",driver)
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
        results = []

        configs = load_config()
        for config in configs:
            try:
                if config.get("loginMethod"):
                    sso_login(driver, wait, config, results)
                else:
                    normal_login(driver, wait, config, results)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Exception in processing {config.get('Domain_Name', 'Unknown')}: {e}")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to initialize WebDriver or load configuration: {e}")
    finally:
        time.sleep(5)
        driver.quit()
        print("Browser closed")

        df = pd.DataFrame(results)
        df.index += 1
        df.index.name = "S.No"
        df.to_excel('login_results.xlsx', index=True)
        print("Login results saved to login_results.xlsx")
        file_path = r'C:\Users\affine\Desktop\automation\login_results.xlsx'
        send_email(subject='Affine Applications Status Reports ', body='Open file for result', to_email="hari.om@affine.ai",file_path=file_path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

